# Why $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ is subgroup of $S_{7}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

In one the solutions of my Abstract algebra question, It was written,

$\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ is not a subgroup of $S_{6}$.

$\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ is a subgroup of $S_{7}$.

$\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ is  a subgroup of $S_{9}$ and

$\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ is a subgroup of $S_{11}$.

But my question is, since this groups $S_{6}$,$S_{7}$, $S_{9}$ and $S_{11}$ are non abelian group, how can we be sure whether it has $\Bbb Z_{6}$ is its subgroup or not?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hint: find an element of order 12 in $S_7$.

Comment: Hint: Prove that the group generated by $(1234)(567)$, or $\langle(1234)(567)\rangle$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Answer (score 4):

HINT: What is the order of the permutation $(1234)(567)$?

Answer (score 2):

It helps to realize that $\Bbb Z_{12} \cong \Bbb Z_3 \times \Bbb Z_4$.  If you look at it that way, it's easy to see how to inject $\Bbb Z_{12}$ into $S_7$.